# when i click on update button i got data to be updated but it gets cleared when i move to update page in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
$scope.fetchDataForEditInvoice = function (row)
{
    var index = $scope.gridOptions.data.indexOf(row.entity);
    var InvoiceId = $scope.gridOptions.data[index].InvoiceId;

    var status = angularService.FetchDataForEditInvoice(InvoiceId);
    status.then(function (invoiceData) {
        console.log(invoiceData);
        window.location.href = "/Invoice/AddInvoice";
        $scope.InvoiceDetails = invoiceData.data.InvoiceDetails;
    },
    function () {
        alert('Error in fetching record.');
    })
}
```

on click of update button i call following function and i got data but how i can assign it to controls on update page

Answer (score 0):

save invoiceData.data.InvoiceDetails in a $rootScope variable. So it will available in all controllers.

```
$rootScope.InvoiceDetails=invoiceData.data.InvoiceDetails;
```

inject $rootScope to your controller before using it.
Use routers traversing next page.Refer Single Page Apps with AngularJS Routing][1](https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating)